# Android Auto and TensorFlow?

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow

Is it possible to implement TensorFlow to an Android AUto application? If yes... Can I also use the infotainments GPU for computing ? When I use TensorFlow with Python I can choose between the GPU CPU or both togehter... If I can use TensorFLow with Andorid Auto is it somehow possible to sign tasks to the GPU of the infotainmentsystem and to the phones CPU at the same time? I tried to find informations about this topic via goolge but without any results so far. I am happy about any thoughts and help. Please bear with me I am new to Android Auto and just very curious.

Comment: [Android Auto](https://developer.android.com/auto/) is more of a UI/UX for automobile, similar to second screen with limited access to anything on the car. Given the lead time for development of in-car infotainment system (years), the GPU would be anemic.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. That makes sense!